Python logging loop without new lines
Is it possible to use the logging module to display information about the progress in a loop without printing hundreds of new lines?
Let me illustrate with this snippet:
for n in range(99999999):
    if n%99999 == 0:
        msg = f'Completed {n} iterations'
        print(msg + '\b'*len(msg), end='')

Is it possible to replicate this behavior with logging? Something like:
with logging.end(''):
    for n in range(99999999):
        if n%99999 == 0:
            msg = f'Completed {n} iterations'
            logging.info(msg + '\b'*len(msg))


you could use  the tqdm which is built for such purposes, unless you want to do this without any other packages

Since logs may be written to a file immediately, or sent to other external services, it's hard to delete content from there again…

Looking for Python native solutions as I cannot install things where this will be running. @deceze I see, makes sense.

Since python 3.2, you can set the terminator from the StreamHandler
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger('service-name')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.terminator = ''
logger.addHandler(sh)

for n in range(100):
    if n % 10 == 0:
        msg = f'Completed {n} iterations'
        logger.info(msg + '\b'*len(msg))
        time.sleep(0.5)

Nevertheless, keep in mind that the purpose of a logger is to log the data, not delete it, that's why most of them work in append mode.
I'd recommend you use a progress bar and also log the progress if you need it. If you can't install any libraries, you can find many progress bars online.

just adding as an addendum since you beat me to it, you can set the terminator as \r which is a carriage return. This eliminates the need to string build with \b but comes with the caveat that if your next output is smaller there is some leftover parts of the previous string left

Yeah, absolutely! I just wanted to replicate the original print
